# PostgreSQL query for tvshows with multiple genres

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a database of tvshows that I have personally watched.

I have 3 tables:
tvshow_list: id, title, episodes, year

genres: id, genre name

genres_in_tvshows: genreid, tvshow id

I want to have a list which would show the tvshow id, title, episodes, and the genres. I cannot find a psql query that shows me how to 1. "group_concat" the genres so more than one shows and 2. join the tables

Answer (score 0):

First your genres_in_tvshows table should have foreign keys referencing table tvshows and genres :

```
create table genres_in_tvshows 
( genre_id integer, tvshow_id integer
, constraint pk primary key (genre_id, tvshow_id)
, constraint fk_tv foreign key (tvshow_id) references tvshow_list(id)
, constraint fk_ge foreign key (genre_id) references genres(id)) ;
```

Then you can use the following query :

```
SELECT tv.*, ge.*
  FROM tvshow_list AS tv
 INNER JOIN genres_in_tvshows AS gt
    ON gt.tvshow_id = tv.id
 INNER JOIN genres AS ge
    ON ge.id = gt.genre_id
```